# import タグはどのような質問に使うべきか？

Tags: 討議, タグ

[import](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import) というタグがあり、恐らく初めは「モジュールのインポート」という文脈で作成されたようですが、タグ wiki の説明が無いため「(CSV 等の) データのインポート」という意味でも使われるようになりました。

- [カレントフォルダからimportされるのを防ぐ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/69109)
- [django-import-exportを用いて、同じテーブルからの数パターンのインポート、エクスポートの方法はありますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/88294)

単語の意味そのものとしてはどちらも間違っていないのかもしれませんが、質問を絞り込むという目的で見ると両者が同列に扱われるのはあまり有用でない気がします。

[import](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import) はどのように使うべきでしょうか？

---

なお、英語版においては以下のように細分化されているようです (あくまで一部)。

- [import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import)
- [python-import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-import)
- [import-from-excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import-from-excel)
- [import-from-csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import-from-csv)
- [django-import-export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-import-export)

Answer (score 5):

個人的には、少くとも今の [import](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import) タグの質問については、すべて不要なんじゃないか、と思っています。

というのも、現状の質問たちにおいて、 import が問題になっているのは、

1. 特定言語(e.g. python) の import の使い方について
2. 特定ライブラリを利用する上での問題について

であって、 import のタグそれ自体よりも、より良いタグ (言語だったりライブラリ名だったり) があるように思います。

なので、今今はすべて削除して、再度 [import](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/import) を利用したくなったら、その時に改めて検討する、で良い気がします。